# Passing data from activity to fragment transaction.replace()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem when passing data from activity to fragment(fragments are overlapped):
I need to pass arraylist with integer that contains id of checkboxes to checked...

Before passing data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C739o.png)

After pass data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ZwN.png)

Code to pass data from activity to fragment:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);
    System.out.println("PERO:" + bundle);

    MyListFragment myFragment = new MyListFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);

   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment);


    transaction.commit();
```

code to get data:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();
        try {
        bundle = getArguments();

        System.out.println("BUNDLES:" + bundle);
        //if (bundle != null) {


                strtext = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("oki");
                System.out.println("AH:" + strtext);


        //}
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more code and context about what the app is doing.  If the `Fragment` already exists, do not create a new instance of it and apply in a transaction.  Consider going with an architecture like MVC or MVVM or MVP to have clear division of concerns within the code.

Comment: can you make me an example with code how fix my issue?thanks

Comment: Not without understanding better what the code trying to do and how it is structured. Based on the images, I suspect there is a `Fragment` or `ViewPager` containing fragments already on screen but the `Activity` is trying to update the contents of an existing `Fragment`. Just my guesses based on what I'm seeing and the little snippet of code you've provided. In a simple implementation, if the `Fragment` depends on something to "tell" it what to select, it either needs that info when it is created (via `Bundle`) or it needs an interface to call to get that info.

Answer (score 0):

in `MyListFragment`

```
private ArrayList mArrayList;

public void setArrayList(ArrayList arraylist)
{
    this.mArrayList = arraylist;
}
```

you can access `mArrayList` anywhere

then do

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);
    System.out.println("PERO:" + bundle);

    MyListFragment myFragment = new MyListFragment();
    myFragment.setArrayList(hm);


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment);


    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: fragments are always overlapped

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity

```
     private List<Data> List = new ArrayList<>();        

     FragmentName FragName = new FragmentName();
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();                              
     bundle.putParcelable("key",List);
     FragName.setArguments(addEditBundle);
    
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.replace(R.id.container, FragName);
    
     transaction.commit();
```

In your Fragment

```
     private List<Data> List = new ArrayList<>();  
     List  = getArguments().getParcelable("Key");
```

Comment: fragments are overlapped because the problem is transaction.replace(R.id.container, FragName);

Comment: you can use  transaction.add(R.id.container, FragName);

Comment: same problem also with transaction.add

Comment: if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_screen) != null) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            } /

Comment: where i must put this code? can you update your answer please?

Comment: try this
You should set background at your fragment  XML file

Comment: if i set background color white my new fragment is overlapped to other fragments....so i can't scroll tabs with  view pager

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter