# Retrieve the loaded fragment and execute a function in its class

Tags: android, android-fragments

Am performing a http request and using interfaces to know when its complete

In my main activity am attaching my fragment like this

```
public class HomeActivity extends SharedBaseActivity implements HomeCategories.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
          onGeneralApiRequest{

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     loadfragment(0)
    }


     void loadFragment(int position) {
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        HomeCategories categories = new HomeCategories(); ///the fragment
       switch(position){
         case 0:{
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_fragment_loader, categories);
            break;
         }
       }
      }


  @Override //this is an overide for the apiresponse callback
public void onApiResponse(JSONObject response) {
    //here am stuck
    //am supposed to call the loaded fragment above and execute a function on the fragment class
}


 }
```

Now in the home categories fragment i have a method that sets the data

```
setData(DataModel data){
   categories = data; //sets the categories
  }
```

Now as from the above code i would like to retrieve the loaded fragment and call the method setData on the fragment. That is i have other fragments that am dynamically loading in the switch case block.
I have added the setData method to all of them (fragments)

EXTRA INFORMATION ON MY SETUP

For the id home_fragment_loader in xml it looks like

```
//...other parts of the layout

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgren"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bar_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_loader"
        ></RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

For the onGeneralApiRequest its an interface located on its own class

```
public interface OnGeneralApirequest {
   void onApiResponse(JSONObject response);
    void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error);
 }
```

I have checked on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302443/passing-data-from-activity-to-fragment-transaction-replace) but it doesnt show how to retrieve the loaded fragment and execute a method in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(). 
          replace(R.id.home_fragment_loader, categories, "HomeTag").
          commit();
```

and then you can retrive using

```
((HomeCategories)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HomeTag")).setData(your_data)
```

Comment: (HomeCategories)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HomeTag") always returns null

Comment: i have added it in my onApiResponse and am gettting a null pointer exception

Comment: Have you added the tag while adding the fragment?

Comment: yes like this   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_fragment_loader, categories, "CATEGORIES");

Comment: also the method which initiates the http request is called in the fragment onAttach life cycle

Comment: oh i see my problem i wass calling getFragementManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager, thanks it now works

Comment: You have replaced the fragment but not commiting the transaction so add .commit() at the end of transaction
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_fragment_loader, categories, "CATEGORIES").commit()

Comment: Yeah please make sure if you are using support.v4.Fragment then use supportFragmentManager not app.FragmentManager